# What if delete bounty question?

Tags: discussion, bounty

What happens if I offered bounty, after giving bounty, I deleted that question? Do I get my bounty reputation back??

Comment: Short answer is: No.

Comment: You can't delete a question with answers *anyway*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, Actually, I got one bounty with 5-6 upvotes, and after some days, that question got deleted. I don't know how and why. so I asked

Comment: Ah, you *received* a bounty, but because the [whole question was deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30368329/network-bandwidth-speed-tester-in-javascript-ajax-or-jquery) your answer was deleted too, and together with that *all reputation you earned* was deleted. Yes, you lost the bounty.

Comment: And I was wrong; bounties are refunded when a post is deleted. I don't think it even matters if the bounty was awarded or not. It is just not that common for questions to be deleted by community vote where a bounty was involved, such as in your case.

Comment: Yea, I was always under the impression that a bounty's rep is lost to the person offering the bounty, no matter what. Then I found that answer... Figured I'd let a moderator answer this question. Good to know.